# Set React Component to Horizonal scroll on mouse wheel

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a react component that displays a list of images horizontally across the page.

I would like to be able to scroll horizontally through them without having to hold in the SHIFT button.

Is there a way I change the default for just this component using css or react?

Here is my code:   https://codesandbox.io/s/team-grid-slicer-2db8d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `ref` and bind it to your `div` which you will scroll. Here is a [working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/team-grid-slicer-forked-n4ubs?file=/src/App.js)

Basically you create a ref and assign it to the div

```
const scrollRef = useRef()
...

<div ref={scrollRef}>
```

And you listen to the changes on the `wheel` event within the div:

```
if(scrollRef.current){
  scrollRef.addEventListener('wheel', /* your function */)
}
```

And you scroll to left, instead of down based on the wheel event's deltaY:

```
 el.scrollTo({
      left: el.scrollLeft + e.deltaY * 5,
      behavior: "smooth"
  });
```

*PS: You can remove `* 5` but it looks better imo*

Answer (score 0):

just add an `id="container` to your component and then add

```
            onWheel={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault()
              var container = document.getElementById('container')
              var containerScrollPosition = document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft
              container.scrollTo({
                  top: 0,
                  left: containerScrollPosition + e.deltaY,
                  behaviour: 'smooth' //if you want smooth scrolling
              })
            }}
```

This will listen to the onWheel and scroll your component.